# Convert LoverCase to UpperCase and converse (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase, lowercase

Have a string for example = 'fGvB233k;'
need result = 'FgVb233K;'

```
<script>
        var str ='fGvb233k;';
        var res;
        var i;
        for (i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase())
            {
            str[i] = str[i].toLowerCase() ; 
            console.log(str[i]);
            }
            else {
             str[i] = str[i].toUpperCase() ;     

            }
        };
        console.log(str);
    </script>
```

my script doesnt work....
result of script:
 G
 B
 2
 3
 3
 ;

Comment: Declare `var i` before the for loop

Comment: ^^ that has nothing to do with it. You cannot mutate a string, you need to make a new one

Comment: added but still not work (

Comment: john look at my answer below, the var has nothing to do it it

Comment: thanks! all works!

Comment: no prob, why did you select a different answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qimoce/2/edit?js,console)
You cannot mutate a string you need to create a new one:

```
var swapCase = function(letters){
    var str = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<letters.length; i++){
        if(letters[i] === letters[i].toLowerCase()){
            str += letters[i].toUpperCase();
        }else {
            str += letters[i].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    console.log(str);
    return str;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str ='Aren;';
var res = "";
for (let i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
     if(str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase())
     {
        res += str[i].toLowerCase();
     }
     else {
        res += str[i].toUpperCase();
     }
}
// see the result's output
console.log(res);
```

try this one;

reason why you can't see result is that strings are immutable arrays of chars
and you need to create something like "string builder" and then "build" your string

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to change all lowercase strings to uppercase strings and vice versa.

```js
`<script>
var str = 'fGvB233k', char='', result = '';
var i=0;

while (i <= str.length) {
    char = str.charAt(i);

    if (!isNaN(char * 1)) {
        result += char;
    }
    else {
        if (char === char.toUpperCase()) {
            result  += char.toLowerCase();
        }
        if (char === char.toLowerCase()) {
            result += char.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    i++;
}
console.log(result);
</script>`
```

Note that I also did a check for the numbers and

Answer (score -1):

You have to store the changes into a new variable since you can't mutate a string

```
  var input ='fGvb233k;';
  var output = '';

  for (var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase())
    {
      output += input[i].toLowerCase() ; 

    }
    else {
      output += input[i].toUpperCase() ;     

    }
  };
  console.log(output);
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is almost the exact same solution that was accepted.